# ¿como hacer que cuando le de click a la opcion NO de un confirmdialog se quede ahi en un formulario jframe?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

como hacer que cuando le de clic a la opción NO de un `confirmdialog` se quede ahí en un formulario jframe de [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans)?

```
private void jButton3MouseClicked( java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt ) {
    int ax = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, 
        "Esta Seguro Que Desea Salir?"
    ); 

    if ( ax == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null, 
            "Hasta Pronto,Que Tengas Un Buen Dia."
        );
    }
    System.exit(0);

    if ( ax == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null, 
            "Has seleccionado NO."
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Comment: Hola, no entendí tu pregunta. Trata de concretar y cuida un poco la presentación.

Comment: ok amigo lo que pasa es que he hecho un confirmdialog para la salida de un programa osea un cuadro de confirmación donde aparece las opciones SI-NO-CANCELAR donde si le doy si el programa saldrá pero si le doy no también se sale  y no tiene porque salirse el debe quedarse ahí y ese es el problema que tengo :(

Comment: Tendrías que poner tu código, pero tu problema va a ser con como gestionas la respuesta. El cuadro de dialogo te devuelve un entero. Según el valor debería cerrarse o no el programa, comprueba la validación con las diferentes opciones.

Comment: private void jButton3MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
int ax = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Esta Seguro Que Desea Salir?");
        if(ax == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hasta Pronto,Que Tengas Un Buen Dia.");
        System.exit(0);
        
        if(ax == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has seleccionado NO.");

Comment: alli esta el codigo amigo

Answer (score 1):

En el siguiente ejemplo puedes ver como se almacena el valor devuelto por la ventana en la propiedad "res", de tipo entero:

```
package pruebas;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestConfirmDialog {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
        null, 
        "¿Quieres continuar?", 
        "Confirm",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
        JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE
    );
    if ( res == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION ) {
      System.out.println( "Seleccionaste NO" );

    } else if (res == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      System.out.println( "Seleccionaste SI" );

    } else if (res == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) {
      System.out.println( "Cerraste la ventana" );
    }

    System.out.println( "Valor devuelto: " + res );
  }

} //class
```

> Un par de páginas que desarrollan el tema (en inglés):
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html
>   http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/UsingJOptionPanetopromptuserconfirmationademo.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ax == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION ) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
            null, 
            "Hasta Pronto,Que Tengas Un Buen Dia."
        );
           System.exit(0);

    }
```

así quedaría tu código

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.